How kill previous activities
In my app I have in the mainActivity intent that move mw to the second activity and in the second activity I have also intent that move me to the main activity.
Now when I press the back button in my phone it return's me to the last activity that i was in but it not the problem, I already know how to disable pressing back button but I
dont want that when I move to another activity the last activity that I was in will keep running I want to stop it from running or either to complete kill it.
Any ideas?

Call finish()

You can achieve this by calling finish() in your second activity after starting MainActivity
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    this.finish()


Just call:

finish()

startActivity(Intent(this@FirstActivity, SecondActivity::class.java))
finish()

